# Bulding One page nav with anchors?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Unfortunately i am stuck with building a navigation for my full page sections widget.

Im extending `apostrophe-pieces` for my the sections itself in

```
lib/modules/sections/index.js


  module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'section',
  label: 'Section',
  pluralLabel: 'Sections',
  contextualOnly: false,
  addFields: [
    // Main Fields
    { name: 'title', label: 'Section Title', type: 'string', help: 'Select Title' },
    { name: 'color', label: 'Section Color', type: 'color', help: 'Select color' },
    // Backgrounds
    {
      name: '_image',
      type: 'joinByOne',
      withType: 'apostrophe-image',
      label: 'First Section Image',
      filters: {
       projection: {
         attachment: true,
         description: true,
         title: true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  // Fields Arrangement
    arrangeFields: [
    { name: 'basics', label: 'Basics', fields: [ 'title', 'color' , '_image' ] },
  ]
};
```

---

And using `apostrophe-pieces-widgets` for display the sections on `home.html`

```
lib/modules/sections-widgets/index.js

module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-widgets',
  name: 'sections',
  label: 'Sections Widget',
};
```

This is the widget itself:

```
lib/modules/sections-widgets/views/widget.html

{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
  <div class="section" id="{{ piece.title | lower }}" style="background-color:{{ piece.color }};
    {%- if data.page._image.attachment -%}
      background-image: url({{ apos.attachments.url(data.page._image.attachment, { size: data.options.size or 'full' }) }})
    {% endif %}
  ">
    <div class="main-content container">
      {%- if piece.title -%}
        <div class="header"><h3>{{ piece.title }}</h3></div>
      {%- endif -%}

      {{ apos.area(piece, 'a', {
        limit: 2,
        widgets: {
          'double': {
            controls: {
              movable: false,
              removable: true,
              position: 'top-right'
            }
          }
        }
      }) }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything is working fine so far but i want to display a navigation which displays every section on in an separate location for example in `home.html`

```
{% block beforeMain %}
{% include "sections-widgets:nav.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the nav html file:

```
lib/modules/sections-widgets/views/nav.html

<div class="nav">
  <nav style="background-color:{{ data.page.nav_color }};">
    <div class="nav-wrapper z-depth-2">
      <a href="{{ data.page._url }}" class="brand-logo"><h1>{{ data.page.title }}</h1></a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="nav-activator right hide-on-med-and-down">

        // NOT WORKING PART
        {% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
          <li><a href="#{{ data.piece.title | lower }}">{{ data.piece.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        // END OF NOT WORKING PART

        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I've marked the part which isn't working and i downt understand why `{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}` is working in widget.html but not in nav.html. Im really stuck there and I down't know really where the error of my logic is. I would be really thankful for an hint how to pull values of peaces like `title`
in other pages like home and how to build an array which displays all sections titles with links to them.

Best Regards 
Felix

Comment: I was able to fix this with simply putting whole code nav.html in widget.html on the beginning of widget.html now `{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}` is working probably. However this is the sub optimal solution. It would be better to have separate navigation widget like mentioned by Tom.

Comment: If the array you want to display is part of a piece schema, as opposed to a widget, you can do something like: `{% for entry in data.piece.arraySchemaEntries %}` directly in your page show template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is that you're trying to use `data.widget` which only exists in `widget.html`.

If you want to build a navigation widget and use that widget on many pages, you should write this in your `layout.html` at an appropriate point:

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.global, 'nav', 'sections', {}) }}
```

Now you have a widget which is part of the shared `global` doc, rather than being attached to a particular page. And there is no need to `include` anything, because you have put the code in the `layout.html` template that all of your page templates extend.

For more information see the [global doc tutorial](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/global.html) and [using blocks to override parts of the layout](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/editing-page-templates.html#using-blocks-to-override-parts-of-the-layout).

Comment: Thx very much Tom! 
I haven't been thinking about possibility to use data in `global` dock.
But if i add navigation as additional widget whats even better. How can i build navigation items with ` {% for section in data.global._pieces %}` then? I need to call `section` pieces from inside navigation widget, this is an really interesting point because im using all widgets in same architecture as pieces.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean but you can create a join from the global doc, `apostrophe-global` is really just another module that extends `apostrophe-pieces` and supports `addFields` in the same way.

Comment: Then you would edit that join via "global" In the admin bar, picking your pieces. Of whatever type they might be